# Grammar which generate language a^i^2?

Tags: grammar, theory, context-free-grammar, automata, context-sensitive-grammar

Can anybode show what production rules are needed for constructing grammar for language

[image: a^i^2 where ^ means power of]

**Can** it be described by a grammar?

**EDIT:**

This is similar but kind of "weaker" grammar since you are not doing powers but multiples of 2.

[image]

It is context-sensitive grammar, I didn't write down all the rules, but idea is 
of the form:

[image]

You multiply X's with Y and then delete Y on the left side.
I thought that maybe with powers you can generate Y's going to right, and then generate final X's going back right but I think that doesn't really work.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: You should explain what you mean by "^".

Comment: I meant power of ( latex notation)  @MichaelDyck

Comment: At least it can not be described by a context-free grammar (and therefore not by a regular grammar), because it does not satisfy pumping lemma. For a unrestricted grammar, I can't say.

Comment: @Petr I added example why it should be context-sensitive or "stronger"

Answer (score 1):

I've found the following answer here: http://www.mersenneforum.org/showthread.php?t=11676

> ```
> S→LAYR 
> ZA→aAZ 
> Za→aZ
> ZR→AAYR 
> aY→Ya 
> AY→YA 
> LY→LZ 
> YR→X 
> aX→Xa 
> AX→Xa 
> LX→ε
> ```
>
> Since n^2 =\sum_{i=1}^{n} (2i-1), at any instance, for n=i, we have (i-1)^2 A's
>   and (2i-1) a's. For n=i+1, all the A's are converted into a's, and
>   goes ahead.

Though I have not verified it completely.